# Фамилия ФЕЙ во множественном числе

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Как изменяется фамилия ФЕЙ во множественном числе: ФЕЙ? ФЕЕВ?

Answer (score 1):

Если фамилия мужская, то изменяется согласно правилам русского языка, если женская - то нет.

Answer (score 1):

Предыдущий ответ правильный: в Р. п.: нет Ивана *Фея*, но нет Елены *Фей*.

Answer (score 0):

Я конкретно про множественное число.
Изменяется, если фамилия русская (что маловероятно): Иван и Елена **Феи**, (в гостях) у Ивана и Елены **Феев** и т.д.

В отношении иноязычных по проихождению фамилий наблюдаются колебания: братья Гримм, у братьев Гримм, но братья Гонкуры, у братьев Гонкуров. Соответственно, нет однозначности и в отношении фамилии Фей.

Некоторые рекомендации на этот счет есть у Розенталя. "Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке".

Comment: А если "В гостях у Ивана и Елены Фей? Феев?

Comment: Я давал этот пример. "В гостях у Ивана и Елены Феев". Если же считать фамилию нерусской, то "у Ивана и Елены Фей". Понятно, что тут - заложена повод для постоянных споров. Но правила именно таковы.